# Make two LEDs fade in and out with with different PWM values

Tags: programming, led, attiny85

I have two UV leds, one Vf 3.3V @ 150 mA and the second one Vf 5V @ 150 mA. I need a circuit to make them fade in and out alternatively, *i.e.*, as one goes dimmer the other goes brighter and vice versa. I tried an Arduino PWM transistor approach with the Attiny85 board and the code below and it works, but I need the *ledPin2* led to work with at a lower *maxbrightness*. How can I modify the code so that I can set the *maxbrightness* for *ledPin2* to be around 25, while the *maxbrightness* for *ledPin1* remains 255 and yet both take the same time to fade in and out?

```
int ledPin1 = 0;       
int ledPin2 = 4;         
int minbrightness = 0;     
int maxbrightness = 255;    
int fadeAmount = 1;   
int tim=4;
    
void setup()  { 
   pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
} 
    
void loop()  {
  analogWrite(ledPin1, minbrightness);
  analogWrite(ledPin2, maxbrightness);
  minbrightness = minbrightness + fadeAmount;
  maxbrightness = maxbrightness - fadeAmount;
  if (minbrightness == 0 || minbrightness == 255 ){
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount ;
  }
  delay(tim);
}
```

Comment: Why not make the change in hardware? Much simpler and no need to change any code. If you really don't want to, why not simply try putting maxbrightness/10 into the analog write for the second LED? You might have to change the variable to a float to do it in the approximately similar time (otherwise you'll only really change a value for the brightness of the second one approximately every 5 counts).

Comment: I'd like a code solution so it's easier to use it in another configurations. Also, if I just divide maxbrightness by 10, I am afraid the leds might get out of synch after some cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have much choice than to come up with a sort of a counter and instead of having a single variable for the brightness of all the LEDs, you'll have to maintain a separate brightness variable for each channel which will have its own unique dimming profile. You'll then have to empirically determine how many counts it'll take for you to decrease/increase the PWM duty cycle on each separate channel (since perceived brightness isn't linear).

Something like this? The brightness of 32 and a modulo 8 was chosen to be a factor of 256, so it's more or less synced.

```
int ledPin1 = 0;       
int ledPin2 = 4;            
int brightnessLP1 = 0;  //begin with the LED off
int brightnessLP2 = 32; //begin with the LED on
int fadeAmount = 1;   
int tim=4;
    
void setup()  { 
   pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
} 
    
void loop()  {
  //counter value accommodates the modulo below
  for(int brightnessCounter = 1; brightnessCounter < 257; brightnessCounter++) { 
     
     analogWrite(ledPin1, brightnessLP1);
     analogWrite(ledPin2, brightnessLP2);
     brightnessLP1 = brightnessLP1 + fadeAmount; 
     if(brightnessCounter  % 8) {
       brightnessLP2 = brightnessLP2 - fadeAmount;
     }
     delay(tim);
  }
  fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
}
```

I'm sure you could make it cleaner or link the brightness values to the counter, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. I can work from there.

Comment: Of course, you're welcome!